# Melhorar performance para a criação de modelo preditivo

Tags: r, aprendizagem-de-máquina, aprendizado-supervisionado

Eu estou criando um modelo preditivo no R, utilizando a library caret. Quando eu rodo no R ele demora bastante tempo, e ainda da alguns erros. Em comparação, eu rodo a mesma base no Weka em questão de alguns minutos já obtenho o resultado.

Eu já modifiquei as variáveis para inteiro, e mesmo assim não adiantou muito.

Já tentei também utilizar de maneira paralela, mas também não adiantou muito.

Queria saber ao que a performance está ligada nesse caso? Quais são os fatores que mais influenciam para o desempenho ruim na criação de um modelo preditivo?

Comment: O `caret` faz tuning de parâmetros por padrão... Tem certeza que não é isso? As vezes ele está treinando 30 modelos ao invés de 1 como você pdoe estar pensando e ao contrário do Weka. Também tem que ver que modelo você está fazendo. Por exemplo para fazer random forest, o caret pode usar tanto o pacote `randomForest` quanto o `ranger` (e outros), mas sempre tem 1 que é mais rápido.

Comment: Como funciona o tuning? Eu cheguei a rodar com tuning=10 e 20. Mas também não tive melhoras. Eu estava fazendo inicialmente o kNN, pois ele é mais rápido, mas testei o randomForest e também caio no mesmo problema... demora e nada de resultado. Quando eu rodo pra uma amostra do dataset até funciona. Acompanhando o desempenho de memória, eu acredito que ele esteja treinando vários modelos mesmo, como eu configuro somente pra um?

Comment: Tem que ver o seu código... Você mexe nisso com o argumento `tuneGrid`. Também tem que mexer no `tuneCtrl` pq o caret também faz CV. Como fazer está aqui: https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#basic-parameter-tuning Se você colocar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível na sua pergunta fica mais fácil de responder. Do jeito que está a sua pergunta a resposta tem que ser muito longa para atender.

Comment: Esse parâmetro `number` é o número de *folds* de Cross-Validation. Ou seja 10 quer dizer que para cada elemento do grid de parâmetros vc vai ajustar 10x o modelo, para avaliar o erro na outra parte da base.

Comment: `inTain <- createDataPartition(y = make.names(rf$class), p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

training <- rf[inTain,]
teste <- rf[-inTain,]

set.seed(234)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

model <- train(as.factor(class) ~., 
                data = training, 
                trControl=train_control, 
                method="rf")`

Eu estou rodando esse código para uma tabela com mais ou menos 50k linhas e 60 colunas

Comment: Certo, mas quando eu rodo no Weka também faço um CV de 10.

Comment: Depois de mais ou menos uma hora rodando,deu erro de novo.

_Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ter uma série de motivos para ficar lento:

- Algoritmo lento. O `randomForest` não é o pacote mais rápido: tente usar `ranger` ou `Rborist`. [Fonte](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/37382/44359). [`xgboost`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) também é rápido para caramba e fazendo alguns tweaks da para ajustar random forest por ele.
- O caret está fazendo tuning dos parâmetros. Passe somente uma combinação de hiper-parâmetros usando o argumento `tuneGrid`.
- É bem provável que os algoritmos em R tenham performance inferior que o Weka (em C), mas você pode usar o Weka pelo R (procure pelo pacote `RWeka`)

Difícil dizer porque acontecem os erros sem ver os seus dados. Eu chutaria que é porque tem alguma de suas variáveis que possui uma classe rara e quando você faz o cross-validation, algum dos folds fica sem ela.

Sempre tente procurar algum pacote de R que utiliza algum algoritmo em C/C++ para treinar os modelos. Nesta parte de machine-learning, R deve ser considerado apenas como uma interface, para usar algoritmos de diversas fontes de forma mais fácil e geralmente padronizada.